# Jquery Can't insert in HTML through .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding Dynamic Code from one Div through Ajax and i also want to add some javascript but it cant display on code my code is given below..

```
$.ajax({
              url: "ajax_add_logo_parts.php",
              data: 'act=getPartImage&part_id='+part_id+'&list_id='+n[1],
              success: function(msg){

                    alert($("#mainPartId"+n[1]).html());
                    $("#mainPartId"+n[1]).append(msg)
                    alert(msg);
                    alert($("#mainPartId"+n[1]).html()); 
                    $("#"+n[0]).val(color)                  
                }
            });
```

Variable msg contain some html and javascript which is given below but it cant be able to display in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var capPartId1 = document.getElementById("capPartId1");



    var originalPixelsPart1 = null;

    var currentPixelsPart1 = null;



    function changeColorPart1(color)

    {

        $('.bill').val(color);

        if(!originalPixelsPart1) return;

        var newColorLogo = HexToRGB(color);



        for(var I = 0, L = originalPixelsPart1.data.length; I < L; I += 4)

        {

            if(currentPixelsPart1.data[I + 3] > 0)

            {

                currentPixelsPart1.data[I] = originalPixelsPart1.data[I] / 255 * newColorLogo.R;

                currentPixelsPart1.data[I + 1] = originalPixelsPart1.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColorLogo.G;

                currentPixelsPart1.data[I + 2] = originalPixelsPart1.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColorLogo.B;

            }

        }



        ctx.putImageData(currentPixelsPart1, 0, 0);

        capPartId1.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    }

    function getPixelsPart1(img)

    {

        canvas.width = img.width;

        canvas.height = img.height;



        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        originalPixelsPart1 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        currentPixelsPart1 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);



        img.onload = null;

    }

</script>

<div class='capPart1 bill_1' id='1' style='position: absolute;z-index: 600;display: block;'><img src='http://localhost/CustCap/Code/customcap/images/capparts/0630112013030101.png' id='capPartId1' onload='getPixelsPart1(this);'></div>

<input type='hidden' name='bill' id='bill' class='bill' value='' />
```

i can see just below code

```
<div class='capPart1 bill_1' id='1' style='position: absolute;z-index: 600;display: block;'><img src='http://localhost/CustCap/Code/customcap/images/capparts/0630112013030101.png' id='capPartId1' onload='getPixelsPart1(this);'></div>

<input type='hidden' name='bill' id='bill' class='bill' value='' />
```

Comment: Take your JavaScript out of your HTML?!

Comment: what is the value of msg?

Comment: the msg contain second code mins html and javascript

Comment: @Liam : javascript can change dynamically on every click so i need to use and its coming from PHP side

Comment: There are no statements which attempt to insert HTML through `.html()`.

Comment: Does the JavaScript change or does the data that the javascript acts on change? **Seperation of concerns**

Comment: yes it dynamically inserted with code

Comment: html() is not excepting script tags . so it avoids your script.. you have to use msg.innerHtml which you have to pass in argumentes of jquery's html function like $("something").html(msg.innerhtml); this will pass javascript into page

Comment: Not Working BOSS :( i Fetch the same javascript in another function and i will get this but in this function i cant :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       $.ajax({
          url: "ajax_add_logo_parts.php",
          data: 'act=getPartImage&part_id='+part_id+'&list_id='+n[1],
          success: function(msg){

                alert($("#mainPartId"+n[1]+"").html());
                $("#mainPartId"+n[1]+"").append(msg)
                alert(msg);
                alert($("#mainPartId"+n[1]+"").html()); 
                $("#"+n[0]+"").val(color)                  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Same Error Not Display my Javascript

Comment: there is some another problem ...because here syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your `type:post/get` is missing try adding this:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url: "ajax_add_logo_parts.php",
   data: 'act=getPartImage&part_id=' + part_id + '&list_id=' + n[1],
```